# font-face doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

I've used font-face for my website. it shows properly on all browsers except chrome.

what should I do?

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "B Yekan";
        src: url('font/142272950-683a5dddcff7f1cbb08d964cc275cb50ce7840291901931.eot');
        src: url('font/142272950-683a5dddcff7f1cbb08d964cc275cb50ce7840291901931.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/142272950-683a5dddcff7f1cbb08d964cc275cb50ce7840291901931.svg#B Yekan') format('svg'),
        url('font/142272950-683a5dddcff7f1cbb08d964cc275cb50ce7840291901931.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/142272950-683a5dddcff7f1cbb08d964cc275cb50ce7840291901931.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

body{
        font-family: "B Yekan","Open Sans";
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 21px;
        color: #626262;
    }
```

Comment: can you link your site ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have access from your style path to font folder. Is The font folder in the same folder of your style sheet file? try with absolute paths.
regards